# sql select query multiple incomplete words

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

need help for my problem...

i have a record on my database where it contains multiple words in 1 row.

example:

product_name:

```
white sugar big
brown sugar big
white sugar small
brown sugar small
```

now... i made a select query that able to select products even not complete word. i use 'like' here.

```
select * from products where prod_name like '%".$pname."%'
```

note: $pname is a php varriable...

so i tried to query the word "whi"

then the result are:

```
white sugar big
white sugar small
```

now my problem is i want to make my search flexible that if i search the word "whi bi"

the result would be"

```
white sugar big....
```

thnx in adavance =)

Answer (score 2):

Just replace every whitespace with a `%` in your php variable before building the query.

Answer (score 0):

Replace spaces from search term to `%` like 
`$term = str_replace(" ", "%", $term)` then do the db query.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try full text searching in MYSQL which will automatically compile a scored based search:

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

```
select * from products where  MATCH (prod_name) AGAINST ('whi bi')
```

Alternatively, you could explode the word and construct multiple searches:

```
$searchTerms = explode(' ',$pname);
$term='%'.str_replace(' ','%',$pname).'%';
$sql = "select * from products where prod_name like '$term'";
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is similar to the one posted using "%xx%yyy%zzz%" with the `LIKE` keywords. If you expect to have complex search then you can use a REGEXP:

```
select * from products where prod_name REGEXP 'whi[.]*bi[.]*'
```

Then your PHP code would need to prepare:

```
$keywords = "whi bi"; // whatever terms
$search = str_replace(' ','[.]*',$keywords)."[.]*";
$sql = "select * from products where prod_name REGEXP '".$search."'";
```